# iPhone SDK 4 "Half curl page transition"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiviewanimationtransition

In Steve Jobs' keynote announcement of the iPhone SDK 4 earlier this year, one of the slides showed that a "Half curl page transition" was part of the new SDK.

I've looked through the iOS API docs and I can't seem to find this transition. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not a transition, but a `modalTransitionStyle`. You can check the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621388-modaltransitionstyle

If you create a new `UIViewController`, set its `modalTransitionStyle` to `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`, and then `presentModalViewController:animated:` it, you'll get the desired "half curl page" effect.

Answer (score 6):

Are you talking about iBook style page turning animations? There's a blog piece about it here, with links to 2 GitHub projects with it:

http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/

Comment: I wasn't exactly looking for a page turn animation, but that blog post is an excellent read anyways, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you try Manga Rock Unity? They have a page turning really like iBook, moving by fingers. Not private API I guess, or else they cannot be on.

Can ask how they do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout [XBPageCurl project](https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl) on github it also provide example how to do that

Answer (score -1):

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.containerView cache:YES];
```