# Curl an image left to right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

I have an imageview which is a diary showing two pages.
I want an effect such that only half portion of the image that is one page of a diary
just curls from left to right and vice-versa.

So that it brings an effect such that the user is turning the page of a diary.

I have read many articles related to it but I am not getting the desired effect.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want one of many page-curl effects available in iOS and elsewhere. Try this SO thread:

[iPhone SDK 4 "Half curl page transition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133644/iphone-sdk-4-half-curl-page-transition)